# Read values from a textfile, delimited by = and $ signs

Tags: c#, text-files

how can i read from a text file , from a specific location for example i have a textfile

```
pathA = sometexthere$
pathB = sometexthere$
pathC = sometexthere$
TimerTC = sometexthere$
```

I want to read everything between "=" and "$"

To read line by line i'm using this:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("config.cfg");

while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        label1.Text=line;
        counter++;
    }
    else if (counter == 2)
    {
        label2.Text=line;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: so every line of your input should be SPLITTED at the equal sign. How many lines do you have in your file? Do you have enough labels for each line in your file?

Comment: To all users of `string.Split`: it can take an **array** of separators. If you are using Split, consider passig it a `'=','$',' ','\n'` as the delimiter set. You should get an array and all even elements would be interesting.

Comment: BTW. to all current responders: did you notice that there are spaces around '=' sign?:)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: thanks , added your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
int index;

List<string> listLines = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("C:\\Data.txt"))
{
   index = line.LastIndexOf('=');
   listLines.Add(line.Substring(index + 1, (line.Length - index) - 
                                     ((line.Length) - line.LastIndexOf('$')+1)));
}
```

**Solution2:**

you can split every line with delimter `=` and then extract the word starting with `=` ending with `$`

```
string str;
List<string> listLines = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("C:\\Data.txt"))
{
    str = line.Split('=')[1].Trim();
    listLines.Add(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 
                                           (str.Length - str.LastIndexOf('$'))));
}
```

**Solution 3:**

```
List<string> listLines = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("C:\\Data.txt"))
{
    var str = line.Split(new char[] { '=', '$'},
                                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    listLines.Add(str[1].Trim());
}
```

Comment: If you are so sure of the presence of the equals sign then you could also assume the presence of the $ symbol at the end of the line. So remove that ugly calculation or use TrimEnd('$')

Comment: well i'm using this <code>string str;
            List<string> listLines = new List<string>();
            foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("config.cfg"))
            {
                str = line.Split('=')[1].Trim();
                listLines.Add(str.Substring(0, str.Length -
                                                       (str.Length - str.LastIndexOf('$'))));
            }
           worldserverpath.Text=String.Join(Environment.NewLine,listLines.ToArray());
        }</code>  but it copy everything from that file to 1 textbox :| how can i count so it copy line by line ?

Comment: nvm found it :) i had to use textbox.listline[1] :))

Comment: @Maxim: you want to have some delay while displaying the text on textbox?

Comment: @Maxim: Great :) glad tobe help of you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534804%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods:

```
File.ReadLines("path")
    .Select(line => new string(line
                   .SkipWhile(c => c != '=')
                   .Skip(1)
                   .TakeWhile(c => c != '$').ToArray())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using a Regex ([although, now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)):

```
var regex = new Regex(
   @"^             # beginning of the line
    (?<key>.*?)    # part before the equals sign 
    \s*=\s*        # `=` with optional whitespace
    (?<value>.*)   # part after the equals sign 
    \$             # `$`
    $              # end of the line",
    RegexOptions.Multiline |
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace |
    RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Or, a one liner:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<key>.*?)\s*=\s*(?<value>.*)\$$");
```

And then select matches into key-value pairs:

```
var keyValuePairs = File
    .ReadLines("config.cfg")
    .Select(line => regex.Match(line))
    .Where(match => match.Success)
    .Select(match => new
        {
            Key = match.Groups["key"].Value,
            Value = match.Groups["value"].Value
        })
    .ToList();
```